# How to call a function when bValidator function returns true?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, validation

Below is my code, How can I call SubmitMedicalSignup() function once bValidator return true only on submit button click ?

```
  <form method="post" data-bvalidator-validate data-bvalidator-option-validate-till-invalid="true">
    <label class="label required"> First Name <font>:</font> </label>
    <input type="text" name="contact_person_first_name" ng-model="MedicalData.contact_person_first_name" class="form-control" data-bvalidator="alpha,minlen[50],required" data-bvalidator-msg="First Name Required.">
    <button type="submit" name="" id="" ng-click="SubmitMedicalSignup()" value="Register as a physician" class="btn-blue"> Submit
  </form>

<!-- validation -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo FRONTEND_THEME_URL ?>js/vendor/jquery.bvalidator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo FRONTEND_THEME_URL ?>js/themes/presenters/default.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo FRONTEND_THEME_URL ?>js/themes/gray/gray.js"></script>
<link href="<?php echo FRONTEND_THEME_URL ?>js/themes/gray/gray.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').bValidator();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call Action method on submit like  `ng-submit="function_name()"`

```
<form method="post" data-bvalidator-validate data-bvalidator-option-validate-till-invalid="true" ng-submit="function_name()">
```

then it will run first bvalidator function then it will call on submit function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use expressions such as `ng-click="bValidator && SubmitMedicalSignup()"`. It should do the trick but it is not the cleanest way to achieve this. What you could do is call a function in your associated controller that checks if bValidator true and then triggers your function.

Comment: bValidator validation works but form submission stop execution

Comment: the console is empty. SubmitMedicalSignup function is not calling

Comment: Both methods should work. If you're still having issues, you might be having errors somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `validateOnSubmit` option to `false` and call validation with javascript on the form submit, and if there is no validation errors call `SubmitMedicalSignup()`:

```
<form method="post" data-bvalidator-validate data-bvalidator-option-validate-till-invalid="true" data-bvalidator-option-validate-on-submit="false">
   ....
   ....

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stop submit event
        if($('form').data('bValidator').validate()){
            SubmitMedicalSignup();
            $('form').submit(); // submit the form
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    flag = 0;
    jQuery("form").on("submit", function (e) {
        if(flag == 0){
         e.preventDefault();
         if(jQuery('form').data('bValidator').validate()) {
           // Do your processing
           flag = 1;
           jQuery("form").submit();
          }
        } else {
         flag = 0;
        }
      });
```